# How do I get the button label to appear beside the add-in icon for the web version of outlook?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Screenshot of ribbon of web outlook without add-in label, just icon :

[image]

On the web version of outlook, the add-in icon shows without it's label. I would like to have the label appear beside the add-in icon. The desktop version of outlook works fine.  The tooltip on for the add-in icon (web version) shows the DisplayName - Description, but again I need help setting up the manifest to show the label beside the icon for the web version of outlook.  Thanks!!!

and here is part(s) of the manifest (patterned after the manifest on https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Addin-TaskPane/blob/master/manifest.xml

```
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Event Details" />

<Control xsi:type="Button" id="appointmentOpenPaneButton">
   <Label resid="paneAppointmentButtonLabel" />
   <Supertip>
        <Title resid="paneAppointmentSuperTipTitle" />
        <Description resid="paneAppointmentSuperTipDesc" />
   </Supertip>
   <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon16" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon80" />
   </Icon>
   <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
        <SourceLocation resid="appointmentEditTaskPaneUrl" />
   </Action>
</Control>

<bt:ShortStrings>
     <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Temp Group Name" />
     <bt:String id="paneAppointmentButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Temp Button Label" />
     <bt:String id="paneAppointmentSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Set Event details" />
</bt:ShortStrings>
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please show the behavior in win32 and the exact expectation on OWA?

Comment: Hello @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, the win32 shows the label "Temp Button Label" underneath the icon (icon80), whereas in OWA, i only get the icon (icon16) without any label, but on hover, it shows "Event Details - Set Event Details".  I would like the label to appear beside the icon in OWA.  Thank you!!!

Comment: Hi @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT,I forgot to mention that we use 'outlook on the web for exchange server 2016'.  Could this be the reason? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, Unfortunately, there's no way to show the button label beside the icon, this is by design. If this is a design requirement for you, please reach out on our Tech Community page: http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to show the button label beside the icon, this is by design. If this is a design requirement for you, please reach out on our Tech Community page: [aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions)